# store a dict with dicts

Tags: python, json, postgresql, dictionary

I want to store json data into postgresql, the json looks like:

```
 {
    "Name": "transcordero",
    "Direction": "jardin alto 9096",
    "Com": "La Florida",
    "Region": "Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana de Santiago",
    "DirectionGeopy": "Jard\u00edn Alto, Condominio Parque la Portada, La Florida, Provincia de Santiago, Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana de Santiago, 8240000, Chile",
    "Categorias": [
      { "Category": "Servicios de transporte, almacenaje y correo " },
      { "Category": "Servicios de transporte, almacenaje y correo " },
      { "Category": "Servicios de transporte, almacenaje y correo " }
    ],
    "ExtCode": [
      { "Code": "1499-461-CM14" },
      { "Code": "711841-19-CM14" },
      { "Code": "1499-370-CM14" }
    ],
    "lat": -33.5235648,
    "lon": -70.5613059
}
```

This is my model:

```
class Bidder(models.Model):

    Name_org= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    direction_uni = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    com_uni = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    region_uni = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    direction_uni_compl = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    categories = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=500,default="none"))
    ext_code = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100,default="none"))
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
```

I tried using ArrayField to store the list of dicts inside of `Categories`, but i keep getting thsi error: `Error while connecting to PostgreSQL can't adapt type 'dict'`

Comment: There is no one-to-one mapping of a dictionary to a list (which is essentially what the array field is) - you could store the dictionary as text, but that would prevent you from querying its content. You could store the dictionary as a record in a separate table and reference that from the main record. Or you can come up with a specific way to map the dictionary to a list and add that.

Comment: @Grismar well, postgres understands JSON natively, there is a JSON type. I'm not sure how that would work with django (which presumably, this is using) since it is a postgres specific type

Comment: Ah, you're right of course, but then I'd also expect you to use a `JSONField` from Django? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

Comment: I solved it usin JSONField, works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using JSONfield for `Categories` and `ExtCode` in my models, like so:

```
class Bidder(models.Model):

    Name_org= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    direction_uni = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    com_uni = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    region_uni = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    direction_uni_compl = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    categories = models.JSONField(null=True)
    ext_code = models.JSONField(null=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
```

And i had to modify the query too:

```
postgres_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO colection_bidder (Name_org, direction_uni, com_uni, region_uni, direction_uni_compl, categories, ext_code, latitude, longitude) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
record_to_insert = (i['Name'], i['Direction'], i['Com'], i['Region'], i['DirectionGeopy'], json.dumps(i['Categories'], separators=(',',':')), json.dumps(i['ext_code'], separators=(',',':')), i['lat'], i['lon'])
```